# Where to find secure.eyereturn.com appearing on GTmetrix

Tags: page-speed, optimization

I recently decided to test run my website to see how its performing using GTmetrix and the result is very poor (PageSpeed Score - 49%, YSlow Score - 47%). I am seeing a host of issues resorted but one is a bit confusing to me.

> Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
>
> ```
> https://quickresource.eyereturn.com/eyebuild/eyebuild_1_19.js
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/GC.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/actual-offer.jpg
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/and.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/border300x250.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/close.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/copy_01.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/copy_02.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/copy_05.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/cta.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/dot.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/heart_l.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/heart_r.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/logo.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/logo_02.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/mobile.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/offer.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/images/offer_link.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_300x250_EN_v1/index_edge.js
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/GC.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/actual-offer.jpg
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/and.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/bbym-blk.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/bbym.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/borde728x90.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/close.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/copy_01.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/copy_02.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/copy_03.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/copy_05.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/cta.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/dot.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/heart_l.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/heart_r.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/logo.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/mobile.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/offer.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/images/offer_link.png
> (expiration not specified)
> https://secure.eyereturn.com/25127/0324_FF_Offer_728x90_EN_v1/index_edge.js
> (expiration not specified)
> https://animate.adobe.com/runtime/5.0.0/edge.5.0.0.min.js (15 minutes)
> https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js (1
> hour) https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js (1 hour)
> https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)P
> ```

What is "secure.eyereturn.com" and where I can find it and remove it?

Comment: Are you using a cdn? Check your js files it might be modifying your files.

Comment: Yes I am using a CDN. I was begining to suspect the CDN but wasn't sure. Which JS files should I look for?

Or can I just do without this whole CDN thing?

Thanks

Comment: OK not sure why but when I remove ONLY ads in the widget of my [homepage](https://linuxhint.com) then these warning disappears.

So just trying to figure out if this is normal and nothing anyone can do about it.

Comment: What kind of ads are they? Adsense?

Comment: @AbuNooh Yes they are adsense

Answer (score 1):

This comes from your AdSense ads.   You can't control how ad networks specify their cache control headers.    Your only real option to "fix" this problem is to remove the ads.

PageSpeed, GTmetrix and YSlow are a bit dumb about this.   They really shouldn't be reporting the cache control headers of third party resources.   Especially when the resources are loaded asynchronously (as is the case with AdSense).